# Где можно найти инструкцию по ssh протоколу?

Tags: ssh, криптография, byte

Нужны ссылки на то, как устроен ssh протокол побайтово.

Я не могу использовать библиотеки в проекте, и стоит задача написать с нуля. Я дошел до этапа diffi-helman KEX reply, исправляя код по wireshark и образцу подключения putty -> openSSH server.

Проблема в том, что далее идет зашифрованная  часть. Начиная с (21) New keys.
RFC 4253/4254/4251 читал, но или не понял или там этого нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине сверху образец, а снизу моя реализация.

Comment: открой исходники openssh и копипастни)

Comment: Если проект требует велосипедить криптографию с нуля - рекомендую валить с этого неадекватного гнилья

Comment: https://libssh2.org/